# Blender 3.6 Transform Panel, adjust amount of rotation for one click?

Tags: settings

[image]

Hi, I mean the little arrows in the marked area. It was 0.1 degree per click (and also when hold & drag the minimum steps) before but now it's 1 degree after Blender 3.6.
I do product renders and I used to adjust camera angle here. But now 1 degree is way too big, I have to type in a number or use R key + XYZ key which  IMO is not as convenient as befoe.

Is it possible to change it back to 0.1 degree or adjust the number and how?
Thanks

Comment: It seems like that's impossible. Could use Python to make some operators and place some buttons on the UI, but is it really worth the trouble?.. It's possible to make really fine adjustments with regular rotate while holding shift down.